# When do DockerHub auth tokens expire?

Tags: authentication, docker, token, dockerhub

When `docker login` succeeds an auth token is put in `~/.dockercfg`. We are considering deploying a `.dockercfg` file to EC2 instances to all running of containers against private repository images. The alternative would be to run `docker login` on the instances, but I would prefer to give instances an auth token as opposed to an account password.

How long do the tokens issued by `docker.io` last before they expire?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That "token" will last as long as your username and password remain unchanged. It is just a base-64 encoded version of your username and password. The "auth" value doesn't come from the servers -- it is generated by the `docker` CLI in [registry/auth.go](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/94e169b44f3bcc346c7d0f9a733a8c76f1eace55/registry/auth.go#L124)

Comment: And, yes, they know this isn't a great idea: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10318